Confusion regarding differential geometry self study book
I am looking for a book to self study differential geometry. Ideally one with exercises (a bonus if there are solutions). I have read different StackExchange posts and I am considering one (or both?) of the following:

Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (John M. Lee)
Riemannian Manifolds (John M. Lee)

I am confused as to whether the first book is a prerequisite for the second, and generally if the second book requires some differential geometry background already?
Other book recommendations are also welcome.
For context I have covered the following topics:

Linear algebra
Real and complex analysis
Metric/Topological/Normed/Hilbert spaces.
Ordinary differential equations
Some measure theory (in the context of probability).
Some group theory (subgroups, homomorphisms, isomorphisms, quotient groups, orbits, conjugation, Sylow theorems).
The rest is a lot of statistics/stochastic processes which is probably not relevant to this.


Lee's books are probably what I would recommend if you're trying to learn geometry. The thing is, differential geometry is a subject with many viewpoints. What is your objective here? Undergraduate level differential geometry is a lot different than the  topics that these two books cover.
For your question about pre-requisites, yes, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds is a prerequisite, strong one at that, for learning Riemannian Geometry (which is a subject kind of different from classical differential geometry). Also, I would change de Riemannian geometry book from "Riemannian Manifolds" to "Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds". Thy're both by Lee but the second one is better in my opinion.
